# default_scope in Sequel

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sequel, default-scope

In ActiveRecord there is a `default_scope` class method to specify a default scope. For example

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope where(:deleted => false)
end

User.all # => SELECT * FROM users WHERE deleted = 0;
```

How can I do this in `Sequel::Model`?

**EDIT:**

After some googling I eventually found some useful information.

```
class User < Sequel::Model

  # Define some "scopes" (filters on the dataset)
  dataset_module do
    def existing
      filter(deleted: false)
    end

    def active
      filter(disabled: false)
    end
  end

  # This is the equivalent to a default_scope. Set one of the datasets
  # as the default dataset for this model.
  set_dataset(self.active)
end
```

The generated query then looks like this:

```
User.all # => SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`deleted` IS FALSE)
```

*By the way*: The equivalent to `unscoped` is `unfiltered`:

```
User.unfiltered.all # => SELECT * FROM `users`
```

**But**, there is one problem. If you try to update a user you got from an unfiltered dataset, it tries to update the user using the given dataset.

```
User.create(disabled: true, deleted: true)
User.all # => []
u = User.unfiltered.first # => Given user
u.disabled = false
u.save # => UPDATE users SET ... WHERE (disabled IS FALSE AND id = 1)
# => Sequel::NoExistingObject: Attempt to update object did not result in a single row modification
```

**So I am back at the beginning.** Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best workaround is avoiding the problem by not having a default scope.  In most cases a default scope is a bad idea.  If you want most of your queries to use a scope, then apply the scope manually in those queries, don't use a default scope and try to backout the scope in other queries.  A default scope only makes sense if **all** of your queries will use that scope.

You can also handle this by subclassing (User is not scoped, ActiveUser < User is scoped).  However, I find the explicit scoping approach works better.

All that being said, if you really want to use a default scope, the following may work around the issue of updating a model instance outside the model's default scope:

```
User.instance_dataset.unfiltered!
```